# Instance of Task class (Task.Factory.StartNew or  TaskCompletionSource)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

This is probably a pretty basic question, but just something that I wanted to make sure I had right in my head.
Today I was digging with TPL library and found that there are two way of creating instance of Task class.

**Way I**

```
 Task<int> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //Some code
                    return 100;

                });
```

**Way II**

```
  TaskCompletionSource<int> task = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  Task t2 = task.Task;
  task.SetResult(100);
```

Now,I just wanted to know that

1. Is there any difference between these instances?
2. If yes then what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example does not create a "real" task, i.e. there is no delegate that does anything.

You use it mostly to present a Task interface to the caller. Look at the example on 
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx)

```
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    Task<int> t1 = tcs1.Task;

    // Start a background task that will complete tcs1.Task
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        tcs1.SetResult(15);
    });

    // The attempt to get the result of t1 blocks the current thread until the completion source gets signaled.
    // It should be a wait of ~1000 ms.
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int result = t1.Result;
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("(ElapsedTime={0}): t1.Result={1} (expected 15) ", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, result);
```

Comment: To add a bit more detail, TaskCompletionSource is a way of wrapping asynchronous operations that otherwise not currently supported with things like TaskFactory.FromAsync.  One example usage of TaskCompletionSource is to wrap event-based asynchronouns pattern implementations like WebClient.DownloadStringAsync.  For more examples, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As you are not firing any async operation in **Way 1** above, you are wasting time by consuming another thread from the threadpool (possibly, if you don't change the default `TaskScheduler`).

However, in the Way 2, you are generating a completed task and you do it in the same thread that you are one. TCS can been also seen as a *threadless* task (probably the wrong description but used by several devs).

Comment: @PeterRitchie did u read what I have wrote? If you are going to run a code which doesn't need a thread switch but needs to return a Task object, you are doing nothing but wasting time by using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Stop using it and use TCS already.

Comment: @PeterRitchie and `Task.Factory.StartNew` is not a magic bullet and it is not async! You may call it multithreaded but not async. Asynchrony and multithreading is different.

Comment: StartNew is documented as "The action delegate to execute asynchronously".  It may not use a thread to be asynchronous, but it is asynchronous.

Comment: how can a sync core be async? it is not possible.